# Android Studio see which classes and functions my code is passing through?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

How can i see while `debugging` my android app that from which classes and functions my code is passing through.

I know I can print `stack trace` but i dont want to print stack trace only at a particular event, i want to print stack trace at `all events` to see which functions and classes my code passes through ??

Comment: you have to use breakpoints in each method where control goes

Comment: @SurajVaishnav Yes but then I would have to add a lot of breakpoints which I don't want.

Comment: @CommonsWare By "All events", i mean every event like networking call internal working everything, also if I will add breakpoints then there will be a lot of breakpoints which I don't want to add.

Comment: When app is running, in the bottom of the Android Studio instead of "Logcat" pane, tap the "Run" pane. It will list all events